# jsf <t:checkbox> get selected checkbox in backingbean

Tags: jsf, checkbox

I am using `<t:selectManyCheckbox>` and `<t:checkbox>` for checkbox generating.

```
<t:selectManyCheckbox id="selectone" 
value="#{templatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean.objectID}" layout="spread"
styleClass="table" forceId="false" forceIdIndex="false">
<f:selectItems
    value="#{templatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean.selectedMedications}" />
```

and

```
<t:checkbox index="#{row}" for=":Medication:selectone"></t:checkbox>
```

and

```
    private String[] objectID;
```

I need to get selected checkboxes in Backing Bean on some button action event. 
Is there any way for this?

---

**My Stuff:**

I tried to fatch `objectID` from backingbean but it's response is not unique everytime.
When I list the objectid sometimes response is proper as required (I mean it shows me selected checkboxes only) and sometime it gives list of all checkboxes regardless of selection.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.getObjectID().length; i++) {
System.out.println("ObjectID is : "+this.getObjectID()[i]);
```

}

Any one have any clue?

Comment: Just to be sure: The value attribute of selectManyCheckbox needs to be a list or similar. Each select item needs to hold a single object. Your variable naming indicates the contrary.

Comment: I got answer. I was using `a4j:commandbutton` and I modified it to `h:commandbutton`. 

But still I can't use `h:commandbutton` as I need oncomplete property of a4j: to call script on same jsp page.

what can I do?

Comment: Are you using jsf 2? Also... It seems that you need to update your answer

Comment: No 1.2 actually I have only 70 points so ... :( I can't update my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I got answer. I was using a4j:commandbutton and I modified it to h:commandbutton. But still I can't use h:commandbutton as I need oncomplete property of a4j: to call script on same jsp page. what can I do?*

Render that script conditionally.

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.submitted}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        callYourJavaScriptFunctionHere();
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Where `#{bean.submitted}` should of course evaluate `true` only when the submit has performed.